# SQL query alphabet /text/ string do not matches

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sqlyog

Whenever I enter a number eg: "123" or "12345", if it is in SQL database, then the result is published, but whenever I try to enter a TEXT or STRING (eg: "AJAY", "12A"), even if it is in my database, the value doesn't matches and an error is reported

Also the pan attribute is `VARCHAR` in MySQL database

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\auth.php on line 18

Here is my CODE:

```
<?php

session_start();

$pan = $_POST["pan"];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("e1",$con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT pan FROM form1 WHERE pan=$pan");
$values = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo $values['pan'];

?>
```

Comment: You need to put quotes around a string.  pan='$pan'

Comment: Your code is extremely vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Please use parameterized queries.

Comment: Thnx a Ton, it worked, got it now, thnx Abhik Chakraborty and Andrew Nee

Comment: The most important information came from p.s.w.g. You should thank them!

Comment: @p.s.w.g, yes sir, sure, but it is a demo code, i m working on it

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)